# How can I add text to a card that has been filled with an image for its background?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have added a card to my homepage and used an "Image.asset" in order to give it a background image. I now want to add some text on top of this card but have been unable to figure out how to do so...any help would be much appreciated!

```
Card(  
    semanticContainer: true,  
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,  
        child: Image.asset(  
            'assets/images/image.png',  
            fit: BoxFit.cover,  
        ),  
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(  
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),  
        ),  
            elevation: 5,  
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 9, horizontal: 10),  
),
```

Above is the code that I have so far (without any of the text that I want to add).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This for example implement [Stack](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Card(
        semanticContainer: true,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        child: Image.network(
          'https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/900x900',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        elevation: 5,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 9, horizontal: 10),
      ),
      Positioned(
        right: 0.0,
        bottom: 0.0,
        child: Text('Example'),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, that was just what I was looking for!

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions but as an addon question, is there any way in which I could change the height of this card?

Comment: wrap image with container and you can set it

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Stack](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) or [Container](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) with a decoration.

You can overlap Widgets with `Stack`.

You can set your `AssetImage` with [BoxDecoration](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) of `Container`.